# How to guard against an in invalid operation when trying to get a floating point value from an untyped buffer?

Tags: exception, floating-point

Consider an untyped buffer, `void*`, from which I take several bytes to treat them as a floating-point value, `float` or `double`. Let's assume that floating-point values are IEEE-754 compatible on my machine. Thus, there might be a binary sequence from a buffer that doesn't represent any valid floating-point value. Attempt to operate on such a floating-point variable stuffed with invalid binary would result in a program fault.

How can I guard against a program abort in such a case - that is, how can I get informed about the invalid binary in floating-point variable?

p.s. What is the correct way to extract floating-point from an untyped buffer? I've heard that the trick with union casting like

```
void* buf;  
union U {int i; float f;};  
U *u = (U*) buf;  
u->i = binvalue;  
fpvalue = u->f;`
```

is invalid, even if `buf` is properly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues is that on many systems, a float has to be aligned (e.g. to an address multiple of 4 bytes), while an entirely arbitrary pointer might be unaligned (and the pointer could even point into an unmapped address, e.g. if it is close to NULL).

The other issue is that IEEE 754 floats indeed define signaling not a number-s and so forth. Maybe checking the float values with `isnan` or `isinf` could help.

At last, the IEEE 754 standard is so complex that not every system implements it entirely. You probably have to write very unportable code if you want to be failproof. While I did read in the past that standard, I also forgotten the gory detail.

Comment: Let's assume that buffer is properly aligned. I'm afraid that I'd have program abort even before I managed to call `isnan`, at the point where I assign the binary to a floating-point variable.